# Set Tab Bar image at runtime

Tags: swift, xcode

I wish to change the image of a tab bar item to a new image at runtime subject to a different view being updated.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I've struggled for hours now so any help would be massively appreciated.

Swift 4.2 Xcode 10.1

EDIT:

I've tried setting through self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].image in viewDidLoad in my VC. I've tried sub classing a TabBarController and setting through there, to which I couldn't get the runtime behaviour I was after.

To be more clear, i'm happy with my current selected and non selected image called "globe", but I want to listen out to a variable called "truth" and when truth is true I want to change the non selected image to "globe_red".

It is that behaviour of changing the image during the apps runtime that I am struggling with!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm sorry so much I can't remember exactly. I've tried setting it through the view controller itself, through the TabBarController both to no avail. Will edit my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it!

- Subclass UITabBarController
- In viewDidLoad of your subclass set self.tabBar.items?[0].image and self.tabBar.items?[0].selectedImage to your desired image. Here I am settings the first VC's tab bar item but you can set any with the index or loop through and set all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to change image of tabBar.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img")
```

or for `selectedImage`

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img")
```

Instead of `0` in `items`, you can use your index for selected tabBar.

Comment: I tried  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].image = UIImage(named: "globe_red") in viewDidLoad of my VC, didn't work.

Comment: Make sure that view controller embedded with tabBar.

Comment: Yeah my view controller is embedded with a tab bar controller.

Comment: I can see from printing the instances that the above method does change the image, it doesn't show on the app though. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure, image in assets selected as original image for render as.